# Win32api how to get pixel width of char

Tags: winapi

I know GetTextExtentPoint function can get width of string.
However, I want to get width of char.
Do you know how to get pixel width of char?

I haven't good at english.

Comment: You can have a string that contains only one character.

Comment: that is  make variable when everytime.
I want just use char.

Comment: You don't get to decide the interface of a third party library.

Comment: as I know GetTextExtentPoint have font caculated.
can I caculate font width?

Comment: Of course, you could write a wrapper function that takes a `char` and converts that to the appropriate, single-character string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`GetTextExtentPoint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpointa) is a *deprecated* 16bit function. Use the 32bit [`GetTextExtentPoint32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32a) function instead.

Either way, both functions allow you to pass in a pointer to a single character without needing to include a null-terminator, eg:

```
int getCharWidth(HDC hdc, char ch)
{
    SIZE size;
    //GetTextExtentPointA(hdc, &ch, 1, &size);
    GetTextExtentPoint32A(hdc, &ch, 1, &size);
    return size.cx;
}
```

```
HDC hdc = ...;
HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT) SelectObject(hdc, desired font...);
...
int width = getCharWidth(hdc, 'A');
// use width as needed...
...
SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);
```